# SOAP methods not retuning after configure nginx

Tags: php, magento, soap, nginx

Methods not returning after configure nginx.But it works fine with Apache.I have attached configurations of nginx vhost config and issue screen shot with this.Can you please someone describe me whats wrong I am doing here.

```
server {
listen 80;

root /opt/webapp/;
server_name shoplsstaging.com *.shoplsstaging.com;
index index.html index.php;
autoindex off; # we don.t want users to see files in directories

access_log /var/log/nginx/shoplsstaging.com-access_log;
error_log /var/log/nginx/shoplsstaging.com-error_log;

    location ~ (^/(app/\|includes/\|lib/\|/pkginfo/\|var/\|report/config.xml)\|/\.svn/\|/\.git/\|/.hta.+) {
            deny all; #ensure sensitive files are not accessible
    }

    location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args; # make index.php handle requests for /
            access_log off; # do not log access to static files
            expires max; # cache static files aggressively


            if ($request_method = login ) {
            add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin "http://*.shoplsstaging.com";
            add_header Access-Control-Allow-Methods "GET, login";
            add_header Access-Control-Allow-Headers "Authorization";
            add_header Access-Control-Allow-Credentials "true";
            add_header Content-Length 0;
            add_header Content-Type text/plain;
            return 200;
            }
    }


    location ~* "/.*(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|ico|css|js)$" {
    #       try_files $uri $uri/ @proxy; # look for static files in root directory and ask backend if not successful
            try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
            expires max;
            access_log off;
    }

    location /api {
            rewrite ^/api/rest /api.php?type=rest last;
            rewrite ^/api/v2_soap /api.php?type=v2_soap last;
             rewrite ^/api/v2_soap /api.php?type=v2_soap last;
            rewrite ^/api/soap /api.php?type=soap last;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
            try_files $uri =404;
           # fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
            fastcgi_pass   unix:/tmp/php5-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            fastcgi_read_timeout 3000;
            include fastcgi_params;

    }
```

}

[SoapUI issue screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h5yQS.png)

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume this is something lost in translation, but when you say

> Methods not returning after configure nginx

you're technically incorrect.  You methods **are** returning something, just not the something that  you, or that a SoapClient, expects.   To start debugging this yourself, you need to look at what the HTTP(s) requests **are** returning, and figure out why they're returning this instead of what they should.

From your screen shot

```
Failed opening `Mage/Seachautocomplete/Model/Processor.php`
```

This is a PHP warning, probably from the Magento autoloader.  Magento tried to instantiate the class `Mage_Seachautocomplete_Model_Processor`, but could not.  There is no `Searchautocomplete` module that ships with Magento core, so this is likely a problem with a customization.  Somewhere in your system you have code that looks something like this

```
$o = new Mage_Seachautocomplete_Model_Processor;
$o = new Someotherprefix_Seachautocomplete_Model_Processor;
$o = Mage::getModel('mage/seachautocomplete');       
$o = Mage::getModel('someotherprefix/seachautocomplete');           
$o = Mage::helper('mage/seachautocomplete');       
$o = Mage::helper('someotherprefix/seachautocomplete');               
$o = ->createBlock('mage/seachautocomplete');                   
$o = ->createBlock('someotherprefix/seachautocomplete');               

block="mage/seachautocomplete"
block="someotherprefix/seachautocomplete"
type="mage/seachautocomplete"
type="someotherprefix/seachautocomplete"
```

and Magento isn't able to find the request class, so it shows you that error.

My best guesses would be you've either

1. Failed to upload a module from `app/code/community` or `app/code/local`
2. Are missing a file in `app/etc/module/*`
3. Your new system has its PHP include paths setup differently that the old system